# Pandas drop_duplicates() without empty rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop-duplicates

I have 2 equal columns in a pandas data frame. Each of the columns have the same duplicates.

```
A B
1 1
1 1
2 2
3 3
3 3
4 4
4 4
```

I want to delete the duplicates only from column B so that the goal is like the following:

```
A B
1 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
3 
4 
4
```

I cloned the column B in a new DataFrame and used drop duplicates. The new dataframe with only the column B after drop_duplicates() looks like:

```
B
1
2
3
4
```

But when i took it back to the original data frame it looks like this:

```
A B
1 1
1 
2 2
3 3
3 
4 4
4
```

My Code:

```
df[['A','B']]
df1=df['B']
df1=df1.sort_values()
df1.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
df1.to_numpy()
df['B']=df1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `drop_duplicates`, then reindex your output with [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.set_axis.html) to force index alignment on the first rows:

```
s = df['B'].drop_duplicates()
#s = df.drop_duplicates()['B'] # alternative if you want to consider A+B

df['B'] = s.set_axis(df.index[:len(s)])
```

*NB. this solution work with any original index of `df`, not only with a range index.*

Output:

```
   A    B
0  1  1.0
1  1  2.0
2  2  3.0
3  3  4.0
4  3  NaN
5  4  NaN
6  4  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```py
df['B'] = df['B'].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
# or with DataFrame.drop_duplicates which can take a ignore_index parameter.
df['B'] = df[['B']].drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True)
```

```
print(df)

   A    B
0  1  1.0
1  1  2.0
2  2  3.0
3  3  4.0
4  3  NaN
5  4  NaN
6  4  NaN
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain why you can use `ignore_index` for a dataframe and not for a series. Note: it works only because the OP uses the default `RangeIndex`.

Comment: It's a nice short way, but note that this would fail if the index is not a range (e.g., `df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], 'B': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]}, index=list('ABCDEFG'))`) ;)

Comment: @Corralien I see `ignore_index` for a dataframe in doc but there is no such parameter for series, can't tell much about the design logic.

Comment: @mozway Thanks for pointing this out, your answer is just good for this.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh. That's why you should to explain that. The same method name doesn't take the same arguments because one is `Series.drop_duplicates` and the other is `DataFrame.drop_duplicates`. For a Series, you have to reset manually the index.

Answer (score 0):

If default indices recreate column from list:

```
df['B'] = pd.Series(df['B'].drop_duplicates().tolist())
#alternative
#df['B'] = pd.Series(pd.unique(df['B']).tolist())
print (df)
   A    B
0  1  1.0
1  1  2.0
2  2  3.0
3  3  4.0
4  3  NaN
5  4  NaN
6  4  NaN
```

If any indices also filtere first induces by length of list:

```
L = df['B'].drop_duplicates().tolist()
#L = pd.unique(df['B']).tolist()
df['B'] = pd.Series(L, index=df.index[:len(L)])
```

Or:

```
a = pd.unique(df['B'])
df['B'] = np.hstack([a, np.full((len(df) - len(a), ), np.nan)])
print (df)
   A    B
0  1  1.0
1  1  2.0
2  2  3.0
3  3  4.0
4  3  NaN
5  4  NaN
6  4  NaN
```